# ASP.NET Core 6.0 - How to use JsonPatch in Minimal APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I see `JsonPatch` feature in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0, but it's for MVC. When I do this in codes like:

`Program.cs`

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DecimalJsonConverter());
});
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
...
```

`PlayerModule.cs`

```
public class PlayerModule : ICarterModule
{
  public override void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
  {
    app.MapMethods("/api/portal/player/{id}", new string[] { "PATCH" }, PatchPlayer);
  }
}
...
[HttpPatch]
private async Task<IResult> PatchPlayer(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<PlayerSchema> data) {
  ... // The data is always empty
}
```

where `PlayerSchema` is:

```
public class PlayerSchema {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string EMail { get; set; }
  ... and other properties
}
```

And I call `PATCH /api/portal/player/1` with body:

```
{
  "eMail": "something@some.net"
}
```

And the `JsonPatchDocument` is always empty (Not null, just Count=0).

What is the minimal APIs alternative for this feature, or it should work the same as MVC?

Comment: How are you calling this API? What payload you are passing to it?

Comment: @Chetan Post edited, please get a look.

Comment: Did you see the json patch resource example in the microsoft link which you have mentioned in the question? You are also missing  `[FromBody]` attribute to `data`.

Comment: Could you please share your program.cs codes which is related with the registered service and else?

Comment: [FromBody] added but with no luck.

Comment: Your patch body does not look like a [json patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#json-patch-example) one.

Comment: That's it. My patch is wrong.